# Assign Simple Products to Configurable

Tags: magento-1.9, php, configurable-product

I'm trying to import a lot of Products from my old Shop and therefor I need your help.

My items have a "parent" item which was necessary for my old Shop.

Example:

-T Shirt Batman
--T Shirt Batman Size 6
--T Shirt Batman Size 8
--T Shirt Batman Size 2

I can add every child and parent product into Magento with a PHP Script. Every child needs to have a stock quantity and an own price.

I 've read somewhere that a configurable product is what I'm looking for, because the sizes should be selected by dropdown. Is this correct?

Can you help me:
- Is it enough to declare the Patent product as configurable and assign child products? If yes, how?

- Am I completly wrong and have to take another way?

Answer (score 2):

From your description it sounds like a configurable product is exactly what you are looking for.

What this means is that you will have a product setup within Magento as `Tshirt Batman` This product cant be purchased on its own. From this configurable product you then assign other products that make up this configuration. So for your instance it will be `Batman TShirt` Configured by size. Each size is its own product with SKU and stock and then on the front end you can allow a user to select the size option.

As there are no limits you can take this as far as your business needs to have configurable by X number of options. Size and Colour are common examples that are used.

There is a little more work to it than above but all this information can be found from the official documentation: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product